# Group by on month from date in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I wanted to calculate the subtotals of ProductTypes by month, with a monthly total amount for all the products sold in the month, on Oracle 11g.
Schema:
PurchaseItem (PurchaseID:integer, Supplier:varchar(50),PurchaseType:varchar(20), PurchaseAmt:number, PurchaseDate:date)

```
So, I tried a query:

SELECT month(PurchaseDate) PurchaseMonth, 
     CASE WHEN month(PurchaseDate) is null then 'Grand Total' 
               ELSE coalesce (PurchaseType,'Monthly Total') 
     end AS PurchaseType, 
     Sum(PurchaseAmt) as SummorizedPurchaseAmt
FROM PurchaseItem
GROUP BY ROLLUP(month(PurchaseDate), PurchaseType);


But I am getting the error message: 
ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier

I am expecting Month-wise sales for each productType
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `month` function in Oracle; extract it in some other way, e.g. using the `to_char` function (as in my example).

With some sample data:

```
SQL> with purchaseitem(purchasedate, purchasetype, purchaseamt) as
  2    (select date '2022-01-13', 'A', 10 from dual union all
  3     select date '2022-01-25', 'B', 20 from dual union all
  4     select date '2022-04-08', 'C', 30 from dual union all
  5     select date '2022-05-01', 'A', 10 from dual union all
  6     select date '2022-05-22', 'C', 50 from dual
  7    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  8  select
  9    to_char(purchasedate, 'mm') purchasemonth,
 10    case when to_char(purchasedate, 'mm') is null then 'Grand total'
 11         else coalesce(purchasetype, 'Monthly total')
 12    end purchasetype,
 13    sum(purchaseamt) summarized
 14  from purchaseitem
 15  group by rollup(to_char(purchasedate, 'mm'), purchasetype);

PU PURCHASETYPE  SUMMARIZED
-- ------------- ----------
01 A                     10
01 B                     20
01 Monthly total         30
04 C                     30
04 Monthly total         30
05 A                     10
05 C                     50
05 Monthly total         60
   Grand total          120

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Oracle 11g follows 'dd-mmm-yyyy' format.

Comment: But I got the expected answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, Oracle doesn't store dates in any human-recognizable format, so what you "see" (dd-mmm-yyyy) is due to NLS settings of your database, session or tool you use. In my sample data, I used **date literal** which always looks like that: the DATE keyword followed by date value in YYYY-MM-DD format, enclosed into single quotes.